# Kendo UI / Angular grid - how to collapse a group

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-kendo

I have the following Kendo UI Angular grid:

```html
<kendo-grid id="engagementGrid" options="engagementGridOptions"></kendo-grid>
```

Controller:

```js
$scope.engagementGridOptions = {
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://accountviewserver:8080/api/Engagement"
                    },
                    group: { field: "Name" }
                },
                sortable: true,
                height: 200,

                columns: [{
                    field: "Name",
                    width: "120px"
                },{
                    field: "Project",
                    width: "200px"
                },{
                    field: "StartDate",
                    width: "80px"
                },{
                    field: "EndDate",
                    width: "80px"
                },{
                    field: "PercentEngaged",
                    title: "% Engaged",
                    width: "50px"
                }]
            };
```

What is the proper Kendo / Angular syntax to make the group collapsed by default?

Answer (score -1):

For those that come upon this, add this to your grid options

```
dataBound: function () {
    var grid = this;
    grid.tbody.find("tr.k-grouping-row").each(function () { grid.collapseGroup(this); });
}
```

Comment: As happens a lot with Kendo answers, the question specifies an Angular solution (i.e. not jQuery).

Comment: FYI, the answer I specified is one I'm using in my own Angular implementation, so I did answer the question.